# How to change the caret formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

My problem is that when I paste text into a rich text box I would like to get rid of all the formatting. Now this basically works:

```
private void RichTextBox1_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (hasImage(Clipboard.GetDataObject()))
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }

    RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;

    if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf) || Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        // get rid of formatting
        string append = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
        Clipboard.SetText(append, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
    }
}
```

The problem is: If I previously had formatted text in my rich text box (e.g., bold text) and removed this text, the caret would still be bold (or italic if italic was previously selected - this is easy to spot since the caret would be oblique!). In this case, the text would also be inserted with this formatting. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the entire document of previous formatting, you could do something like:

```cs
TextRange wholeDocument = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd);
wholeDocument.ClearAllProperties();
```

If you want to keep the previous formatting (i.e. you are appending), it looks like this may be useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597038(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that Clipboard.SetDataObject would help me format the new text to be inserted the way I want it to be? In particular, the line of code
`DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, (Object)textData, autoConvert);`
seems intriguing. Thanks for the suggestion, I will further investigate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work: If I replace `Clipboard.SetText(append, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);` with `DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, (object)append, true); Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);` the text is still inserted with the formatting of the caret.

Comment: Gotcha.  Sorry the suggestion didn't work.  Glad you figured out an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although this only solves part of the problem, it is satisfactory for our purposes:

```
rtb.Selection.ClearAllProperties();
```

With this line, the formatting of the selected text is removed. So if you mark some text that is formatted and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, the text from the clipboard is inserted without formattings.

What remains unsolved is how to clear the formattings of the caret if you just remove a couple of characters using backspace.